# How can I scrape the actual hyperlink and make it appear on CSV file along with other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I am trying to web-scrape specific website ( link is below) and generate csv file with data under predefined headers ( see the code). Link is to the page that has new data every day ( it is overwritten).

Problem :

Not able to figure out how to include link within href tag so it is getting printed for each line item. Please help to fix it and/or propose your better solution. Any help is much appreciated.

Link : https://buyandsell.gc.ca/procurement-data/search/site?f%5B0%5D=sm_facet_procurement_data%3Adata_data_tender_notice&f%5B1%5D=dds_facet_date_published%3Adds_facet_date_published_today

Tried to follow examples on the internet and copy the approach used in other lines of code ( above the problematic one ). File is not getting generated and/or column does not have link associated with each line item.

````````````````
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os

filename = "BuyandSell_V3.csv"

# Initialize an empty 'results' dataframe
results = pd.DataFrame()

# Iterarte through the pages
for page in range(0,20):
    url = 'https://buyandsell.gc.ca/procurement-data/search/site?page=' + str(page) + '&f%5B0%5D=sm_facet_procurement_data%3Adata_data_tender_notice&f%5B1%5D=dds_facet_date_published%3Adds_facet_date_published_today'

    page_html = requests.get(url).text
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"rc"})

    # Get data from each container
    if containers != []:
        for each in containers:
            title = each.find('h2').text.strip()
            publication_date = each.find('dd', {'class':'data publication-date'}).text.strip()
            closing_date = each.find('dd', {'class':'data date-closing'}).text.strip()
            gsin = each.find('dd', {'class':'data gsin'}).text.strip()
            notice_type = each.find('dd', {'class':'data php'}).text.strip()
            procurement_entity = each.find('dd', {'data procurement-entity'}).text.strip()
            link = each.find('a', {'href': 'data link'})

            # Create 1 row dataframe
            temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[title, publication_date, closing_date, gsin, notice_type, procurement_entity, link]], columns = ['Title', 'Publication Date', 'Closing Date', 'GSIN', 'Notice Type', 'Procurement Entity', 'Link'])

            # Append that row to a 'results' dataframe
            results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
        print ('Aquired page ' + str(page+1))

    else:
        print ('No more pages')
        break


# If already have a file saved
if os.path.isfile(filename):

    # Read in previously saved file
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    # Append the newest results
    df = df.append(results).reset_index()

    # Drop and duplicates (incase the newest results aren't really new)
    df = df.drop_duplicates()

    # Save the previous file, with appended results
    df.to_csv(filename, index=False)

else:

    # If a previous file not already saved, save a new one
    df = results.copy()
    df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```````````````
````````````````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

> link = each.find('a', {'href': 'data link'})

with

> link = each.find('a')['href']

**Reason**: entire block there is only 1 link with tag A. Also there is no identifier for tag A. So, you don't need to use any identifier.

> {'href': 'data link'}

this is also a identifier / filter but in this case you need to attribute value of href so this does not worked.